# Android convertView proper handling

Tags: android, adapter

I have the following Override of `getView` in my android project:

```
 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     DrawerListItemBinding binding;

     if (convertView == null) {
         binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                 LayoutInflater.from(this.context),
                 R.layout.drawer_list_item, parent, false);
        if (binding == null) { return convertView; }
         binding.setTitle(values[position]);
         convertView = binding.getRoot();
     } else {
         binding = (DrawerListItemBinding) convertView.getTag();
     }

     if (binding == null) {
         return convertView;
     }
     binding.setIsCurrentView(activeIndex == position ? true : false);

     return convertView;
```

I don't think that the second null check `binding==null` is right, since I believe in that case I need to inflate/create a new view from scratch at that point. I am wondering what is the condition if any that the convertView is non null but it is `null` after converting to the proper type with `getTag()` and what the best practice to do if that is the case ... e.g. create the proper view by calling `DataBindingUtil.inflate()`?

The documentation states that one should make sure the convertView is not null and "of the right type". Is it referring to the case that would be hit in the second null check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was confusing a few different things here. In the documentation when it says 
*"Note: You should check that this view is non-null and of an appropriate type before using. If it is not possible to convert this view to display the correct data, this method can create a new view. "*

The second condition only refers to cases when you are using heterogeneous lists. Since this particular problem does not, then it follows that I don't need to worry about whether or not the convert view will be able to be converted to the apposite view to display the right data. Two the `.getTag()` was returning `null` since it was not set in the first place. This can be solved by simply using the generated databinding class type safe `.bind(View root)` method, instead of grabbing the binding from the tag, as follows:

```
  @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
 DrawerListItemBinding binding;

 if (convertView == null) {
     binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
             LayoutInflater.from(this.context),
             R.layout.drawer_list_item, parent, false);
     convertView = binding.getRoot();
 } else {
     binding = DrawerListItemBinding.bind(convertView);
 }

 binding.setTitle(values[position]);
 binding.setIsCurrentView(activeIndex == position ? true : false);

 return convertView;
}
```